# WCF host address question

Tags: wcf

when I setup the wcf service on a web server, I set the end point address as

```
<endpoint address="http://www.mydomin.com/clientname/happy.svc" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              name="happysvcbasic" 
              contract="happysvc.Ihappysvc">

</endpoint>
```

but when type in above address on a browser, I get a different host name, which is the internal server name, such as,

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://internalservername.domain/clientname/happy.svc?wsdl

I tried to add the host/baseaddress tag, but make no difference, what I missed? thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you host via IIS your service in IIS the address is always relative.  Assuming you want to achieve something with your endpoint remove the http://

```
   <endpoint address="clientname"
```

And then your endpoint would be 
              http://localhost/virtualdirectory/happy.svc/clientname

The use for this is when you are exposing multiple endpoints, as each endpoint has to have  a unique address.

[See](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx) or [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749(v=VS.90).aspx) for more information.

If you are trying to setup a different dns address for your service you need to change the way you have hosted your website and use [host headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33487zw6.aspx).

Comment: you are right. I setup the host header in iis/binding and everything is fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you host your WCF service in IIS, you do not get to choose the address, so setting an `address=` in your `<endpoint>` is absolutely useless, as is setting base addresses.

When hosting in IIS, the only things that determine your WCF service address are:

- the IIS server machine name/IP address, plus possibly a port number
- the virtual directory and possibly any subdirectories where your `happy.svc` file is located
- the name of your *.svc file itself, including the .svc extension

So your WCF service address will be something like:

```
http://yourserver:80/VirtualDirectory/SubDirectory/happy.svc
```

That's all there is, and you can't change that (at least not now, in WCF 3.5 - it might be different in WCF in .NET 4).

So now: what is your question, really?